# Problem with matching password and repeatpassword ( Kotlin Jetpack Compose )

Tags: kotlin, validation, android-jetpack-compose, match

I'm experiencing an issue in my application where the 'Password' and 'Repeat Password' fields appear to contain different values when I log them, but in the 'SignUpViewModel', they are treated as identical. This problem occurs immediately after entering the first character in any field and only with the first character. That's why I can't match password and repeatpassword without adding one more char

[image]

[image]

password and repeat-password are same in application, but not in logs

[image: my application]
[image: logs]

but when I do this:
[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2w69.png)
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98pAr.png)
I can create account and they pass even if not same in application

Maybe someone had same problem, I've recently started learning Jetpack Compose.

Comment: If you want people to be able to help you, check this out - [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)